# how to properly convert oracle timestamp to php without using oracle functions, just pure php?

Tags: php

How to convert this Oracle timestamp, without using any oracle function, just pure PHP functions to manipulate this Oracle timestamp?

Like e.g.:

```
12-JAN-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

If I do:

```
echo date('F d,Y',strtotime($oracleTimeStamp));
```

It produces:

```
January 01,1970
```

And if I do:

```
echo strtotime($oracleTimeStamp);
```

It produces nothing at all.

What's the proper way without using any Oracle function at all, just pure PHP to manipulate this Oracle timestamp?

Comment: Any reason why? This is so much simpler with SQL.

Comment: this time stamp is coming from a model object e.g $model->oracleTimestamp ...am not allowed to edit the SQL itself... I already got the data, now i need to format it programmaticaly using PHP..so how?

Answer (score 3):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for this,

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d#M#y H#i#s*A", $str);
```

Comment: i got an error with your solution..Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string   .... `DateTime::createFromFormat("d#M#y H#i#s*A", $model->THETIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Then `$model->THETIMESTAMP` is already an `DateTime` instance. could you `var_dump($model->THETIMESTAMP);`